# How to generate es2017 code with webpack?

Tags: webpack, firefox-addon-webextensions, ecmascript-2017

I am currently migrating an old Firefox extension and want to use the es2017 features.

The dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
  "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
  "babel-preset-es2017": "^6.24.1",
  "eslint": "^4.19.0",
  "gulp": "^4.0.0",
  "web-ext": "^2.5.0",
  "web-ext-types": "^2.0.1",
  "webpack": "^4.1.1",
  "webpack-stream": "^4.0.2"
}
```

My first test file:

```
export class Test {

    async hello(param) {
        console.debug('Test', browser);
        return `Hello ${param}, how are you?`;
    }
}
```

My second test file:

```
import { Test } from './Test';

browser.runtime.onStartup.addListener((a, b, c, d) => {
    console.debug('Arguments:', a, b, c, d);
    const test = new Test();
    test.hello('World').then((result) => {
        console.debug('Result:', result);
    });
});
```

My gulpfile.babel.js:

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import webpackStream from 'webpack-stream';

const backgroundJS = (done) => {
    gulp.src(paths.src.js.background)
        .pipe(webpackStream(require('./webpack.config.js')), webpack)
        .pipe(rename('background.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist.firefox + '/js'));
    done();
};
```

My webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2017']
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

The result in the background.js does not contain any es2017 code...

() = > {} is converted into function form
classes are replaced by something very ugly
and also the new `` String is not there any more...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why do you need gulp when you are using webpack?

Comment: Webpack seems to be unable to do all the other tasks I want to do, like JSON transformation or other...

Comment: What I basically want is to just combine all files that are imported into one running file that can than be used as a content script, that seems to be unable to deal with import

Comment: Check if you have a `.babelrc` and configured other presets/plugins there.

Comment: As you can see, there are no other presets needed. The question contains my webpack.config.js. Also the .babelrc is there but not needed, because again webpack.config.js defines the preset...